# Open Plotly Dash dashboard when executing code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there a way to open the Plotly Dash dashboard, when initially executing the code?, instead of clicking the link generated at the bottom? Preferably in Jupyter Notebook. I know it can be done in jupyter lab using:

```
import jupyter_dash as JupyterDash
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
...
app.run_server(mode='jupyterlab', debug=True)
```

For this project specifically, it needs to be run Jupyter Notebook.

Alternatively, is there a way to generate an icon for the desktop, which runs the code and opens the dash board, when clicked?

Comment: try this: `app.run_server(mode='inline', debug=True')`

Comment: Thank you, I can see from the documentation, that it should work, but unfortunately, it doesn't, any suggestions on why that could be?